# Prove whether distance is attained in subspace

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have the following problem:

Let $V := \{x = (x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^1| \; \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  \frac{n}{n+1} x_n = 0 \}$. First I have proved, that $Y$ is a closed subspace of $\ell^1$. Now I have to prove whether $$dist(e_1, Y) = inf_{y \in Y} \|e_1 - y \|_1  $$
is attained or not, where $e_1 := (1,0,0,...) \in \ell^1$ and $\| x \|_1 = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |x_n| .$ And if so, one should calculate $dist(e_1,Y)$.

I have no clue, how to go from here, maybe it has to do something with the first part (that $Y$ is a closed subspace of $\ell^1$)? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do your natural numbers start with $0$ or with $1$? In other words, is the $1$ in $e_1$ in the zero-th position $x_0$ or in the $1$ position $x_1$?

Comment: @Alan these answers do not help as they use bounded+closed=compact, which does not work here.

Comment: Please avoid "no clue" questions. If you're struggling to start a question, then the standard to do is to look at your notes or book to see if there are related questions with worked solutions, and then you can see if the ideas there work. If they don't, then your question here could explain *why* they don't work. (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infimum is not attained. Here is a sketch.

For $y\in l^1$ to come close to the infimum, it is clear that $y_1\ge0$ and $y_n\le0$ for all $n\ge2$. Otherwise we can decrease the distance to $e_1$ by setting $y_1=0$ or setting positive entries $y_n$, $n\ge2$, to zero (and adjusting some other entries).

Now take $y\in Y$ with $y_1\ge0$ and $y_n\le0$ for all $n\ge2$. Then
$$
\frac12 y_1 = -\sum_{n=2}^\infty y_n  \frac{n}{n+1} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty |y_n|  \frac{n}{n+1}  \le \sum_{n=2}^\infty |y_n| 
$$
and
$$
\|e_1-y\|_{l^1} = |1-y_1|+ \sum_{n=2}^\infty |y_n| \ge|1-y_1|+  \frac12 y_1.
$$
This is minimal for $y_1=1$. This shows $dist(e_1,y)\ge \frac12$.

Moreover, we have equality if and only if
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty |y_n|  \frac{n}{n+1}  = \sum_{n=2}^\infty |y_n|,
$$
which is impossible as $ \frac{n}{n+1} \ne 1$ for all $n$.
So there is no $y\in Y$ such that $\|e_1-y\|_{l^1}=\frac12$.

Now define $$y^k:=(1,0,\dots,0, \underbrace{-\frac12 \frac {n+1}n}_{k-\text{th entry}}, 0 ..).$$
Then $y^k\in Y$ and $\|e_1-y^k\|_{l^1} = \frac12\frac {n+1}n \to \frac12
$. So  $dist(e_1,y)= \frac12$.